# Clementine doesn't stop Playing Music

Tags: clementine

I have a fresh install of Clementine from the ppa, and it won't stop playing music after a track finishes.

The strange thing is that it only does this occasionally, not after **literally** every track.

Sometimes it only doe sit after a few tracks have gone by, but it always does it eventually.

How can I fix this? Is this a bug?

Comment: The title and body seem to contradict. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, regardless the version of (K)Ubuntu / Windows. It occurs when changing to a new album (caused by difference in bitrate?) The music stops at the end of a song (there's no switch to the next).

It seemed that setting buffer duration (sound output) to 0 ms helps. Others report disabling replay gain helps as well.

Comment: I switched to the classic snap version and this solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ReplayGain turned on?  If so, that could be the problem.  It's a bug in Clementine - fixed, but not yet released:

https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/4748